# I confused understanding aspect of tenses

Tags: tense

Please explain aspect of perfect tense and perfect progressive tense. What the differences?
I bet they have same meaning but why do they have different structure ?

Comment: Have you consulted your grammar book? Why couldn't it help you?

Comment: Do you have any examples? Maybe that can help a bit.

Comment: @Droseel I have done it.  But I still cannot understand about the tenses. The examples on book is difficult for understanding by me

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a very common thing for leaners to confuse tenses. If someone added some money to a jar every time someone asked an ELL question that went something along the lines of:

> What is the difference between “He had eaten lunch” and “He had been eating lunch”?

then I’d have enough money to start investing.

I think part of the problem lies in the fact that many of these example sentences are too simple to appreciate the subtle differences in the tenses. I would be unlike to ever utter a sentence such as “He had been eating lunch” unless it was part of some larger context that also mentioned another event. For example, I might say:

> He had been eating lunch when the fire alarm went off.

As [this website](https://leo.stcloudstate.edu/grammar/tenses.html) says:

> Past progressive tense describes a past action which was happening when another action occurred. This tense is formed by using was/were with the verb form ending in -ing.

Notice how their example mirrors mine, in that there is a second event that gets mentioned.

> The explorer was explaining the lastest discovery in Egypt when protests began on the streets.

I suggest you use Google to find more websites that talk more about this topic. There are plenty of them out there. These are hard concepts for a learner to grasp, but I don’t think I can provide any more guidance here that isn’t available elsewhere.